# $f(x)=\arctan(x^6)$, $p$th derivative

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I would prefer an answer to this question: Let $f(x)=\arctan(x^6)$. Does $f^{(p)}(0)=0$ if p is any prime number?

I expanded out the Taylor series for this function, and all of the terms seem to be 0, except for the sixth term. Does this mean that it proves all prime number derivatives to be 0 and x=0?

Comment: $f(x)=\mbox{arctan}(x^6)$ is an even function, so $f^{(n)}$ (for $n$ odd number) is an odd function (differential of an odd, resp. even, function is even, resp. odd), in particular $f^{(p)}$ is odd for any $p$ odd prime, so $f^{(p)}(0)=0$

Comment: Yup, the Taylor series only has terms of degrees that are odd multiples of six. No primes in that lot.