# $f(x)=x^2 \cos(x^5)+x^5 \sin(x^3)$, differentiate

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If $f(x)=x^2 \cos(x^5)+x^5 \sin(x^3)$. Is $f^{(5k)}(0)=0$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$? (Derivatives that are multiples of 5)

I used a calculator to find out that the 20th term of this taylor series polynomial will not be 0 at $f^{(20)}(0)$. So that's one counterexample. But I'm not sure if the calculator is correct, so is there a quick way to check if my results are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is the case with your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098444/fx-arctanx6-pth-derivative), the idea is to compute the power series about $0$:

$$\cos x^5 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} (x^5)^{2k} = 1 - \frac{x^{10}}{2!} + \frac{x^{20}}{4!} - \frac{x^{30}}{6!} + \cdots,$$

$$\sin x^3 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)!} (x^3)^{2k+1} = x^3 - \frac{x^{9}}{3!} + \frac{x^{15}}{5!} - \frac{x^{21}}{7!} + \cdots,$$

hence

$$f(x) = x^2 - \frac{x^{12}}{2!} + \frac{x^{22}}{4!} - \frac{x^{32}}{6!} + x^8 - \frac{x^{14}}{3!} + \frac{x^{20}}{5!} - \frac{x^{26}}{7!} + \cdots$$

and we can see that there exists a term of degree $20$ that has a nonzero coefficient.  In fact, we can characterize all such terms by noting that we are seeking a nonnegative integer of the form $10k + 2$ or $6k + 8$ that is a multiple of $5$.  Since $10k$ is divisible by $5$, $10k + 2$ is never divisible by $5$; however, $6k + 8 = 5m$ is possible if $$k = 5c + 2, \quad m = 6c + 4,$$ and the desired coefficients will be of the form $30 c + 20 = 10(3c + 2)$.  For $c = 0$, we get $20$ as shown above, and the list is $\{20, 50, 80, 110, \ldots \}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$ f $ is an even function, so if $ k $ is odd  then

$$f^{(5k)}(0)=0$$

On the other hand

$$x^2\cos(x^5)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{10n+2}}{(2n)!}$$

$$x^5\sin(x^3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{5n+5+n+3}}{(2n+1)!}$$

in the second sum, with $ n=2 $, we find that
$$f^{(20)}(0)\ne 0$$
and with $ n=7 $, we check that
$$f^{(50)}(0)\ne 0$$